# Why is there a blank page between my title and table of contents page?

Tags: blank-page

I'm kind of new here, so please point out any mistakes I make in asking the question.

I'm trying to make a new Latex document but I'm seeing an extra, blank page between my Title(1st) and Table of Contents(3rd - should be 2nd) pages.

What mistake am I making? Or is there a problem on Overleaf ?

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\cmark}{\text{\ding{51}}}
\newcommand{\xmark}{\text{\ding{55}}}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makenomenclature

% Title page starts here%
\begin{document}

\title{\bfseries \LARGE Estimating Headrooms of Indian ADRs using Stochastic Filtering Techniques\\ \vspace{1.0cm} \Large Under the guidance of\\ \vspace{0.2cm} \LARGE Dr. Rituparna Sen\\ \vspace{0.5cm} \includegraphics[width=2.0cm]{index2.png}\\ Indian Statistical Institute, Chennai \\ \vspace{1.0cm} \includegraphics[width=3.0cm]{index1.png} \\ \vspace{0.2cm} \LARGE Adeetya Vikrama Tantia \bfseries \\ MS14033 \\ \Large Indian Institute of Science Education \& Research, Mohali}
\date{1st August 2017}
\maketitle

%Title page ends here%
%Contents page starts here%

\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\chead{Table of Contents}
\cfoot{Page \thepage\, of $29$}

%Contents Page ends here%

%Acknowledgement Page starts here%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably because `openright` option. Use `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany]{report}` to see if it works.

Comment: Nope. Didn't work

Comment: Probably just because your title page is too big? try reducing the size of your images or something. As an aside, use `\\[0.5cm]` instead of `\\\vspace{0.5cm}` etc.

Comment: In general to create a custom titlepage you should not put that much stuff into `\title` but use the `titlepage`-environment.

Comment: Thank you. I guess my title page was too big. As soon as I reduced the size of the images and the spaces, that extra page disappeared.

Comment: @Troy nothing is wrong about using `\vspace`.

Comment: You should not have to set the header manually, LaTeX usually takes care about it.

Comment: @Skillmon Maybe it's not "wrong" in the OP's example, but (1) `\vspace` is more to type, and (2) it might be "wrong" in some other context. Better to learn the efficient way to do something, IMO.

Comment: @alephzero then I'd use `\vskip` instead of `\\[]`. And on titlepages I tend to use many fills, which would be `\vfill` (for which I'd define a macro to insert multiple fills at once). And while `\vspace` might be wrong in some context, `\\` certainly is wrong in many.

Comment: @Troy Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter Done, thanks for going through the old questions. (Y)

Answer (score 2):

As established in the comments, the problem was that the title page was too big.
(By using the `demo` option in `graphicx` package and playing around with the vertical spacing, it is possible to replicate the problem.)

Anyway, the easy solution would be to reduce vertical spacings or the height of the images you are using -- something that I can't comment about since you might have format guidelines set by your institute etc.

Here's the result if the height of images is reduced (no more empty page between title page and TOC):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{parskip}

% Title page starts here%
\begin{document}
    \title{%
        \bfseries \LARGE Estimating Headrooms of Indian ADRs using Stochastic Filtering Techniques\\[1cm]
        \Large Under the guidance of\\[0.2cm]
        \LARGE Dr. Rituparna Sen\\[0.5cm]
        \includegraphics[height=2.0cm]{index2.png}\\
        Indian Statistical Institute, Chennai \\[1cm]
        \includegraphics[height=2.0cm]{index1.png} \\[0.2cm]
        \LARGE Adeetya Vikrama Tantia \bfseries \\
        MS14033 \\
        \Large Indian Institute of Science Education \& Research, Mohali
    }
    \date{1st August 2017}
    \maketitle

    %Title page ends here%
    %Contents page starts here%

    \tableofcontents
    \thispagestyle{fancy}
    \chead{Table of Contents}
    \cfoot{Page \thepage\, of $29$}

    %Contents Page ends here%

    %Acknowledgement Page starts here%
\end{document}
```

[image]